# Most Powerful Test involving hypothetical distribution

Tags: random-variables, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let  X have the following hypothetical distribution:

$H_0 : P(X=0)=P(X=1/2)=P(X=1)=1/3$

$H_1$: $X$ is continuous and uniform on $[0,1]$.

I am supposed to find the Most Powerful test for testing $H_0$ against $H_1$ at level $\alpha=0.05.$

I know the theory about the MPT theory but since I am new to this, I wasn't able to apply it on the question. Please help.

Comment: What do you get by applying Neyman-Pearson lemma?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: It seems like a natural test to reject $H_0$ if $X_i \notin \{0,1/2,1\}$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$ and don't reject $H_0$ if $X_i\in \{0,1/2,1\}$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. This test has size $0$ and power $1$, but I'm curious how to approach this with Neyman Pearson Lemma. A likelihood ratio I'm getting it $\frac{(1/3)^n \cdot 1_{\cap_i\{X_i\in\{0,1/2,1\}\}}}{1_{_{\cap_i\{0\leq X_i 
 \leq 1\}}}}$